# How do you call a function in React JS once it is sent data from another component?

Tags: reactjs, function, components

For this, I am taking a type of coffee brew and its cost and sending it to another component. The user presses a button in one div, and the other div should update its text from "Hello, How May I Help You Today?" to "One " + coffee + "? That will be $" + price. And so on.

I am struggling to figure out how to start this chain of events though. What I have is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Barista extends Component {

state = {
    text: "Hello, How May I Help You Today?"
}

confirm(){
    this.setState({ text: "One " + this.props.coffee + "? That will be $" + this.props.value});
    setTimeout(() => {this.waiting()}, 5000);
}

waiting() {
    this.setState({ text:"Waiting for " + this.props.coffee});
    setTimeout(() => {this.finish()}, 5000);
}

finish() {
    this.setState({ text: "Here is your " + this.props.coffee + ". Enjoy!"});
}

render() {

    return(

        <div>

        {this.state.text}

            </div>
    )
}
}

export default Barista;
```

Where and how do I call the confirm() function to start this chain of events?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need move `confirm` to the source for the value of `coffee`, like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        text: "Hello, How May I Help You Today?"
    }

    confirm(coffee, value) {
        this.setState({
            coffee,
            value,
            text: "One " + coffee + "? That will be $" + value
        }, setTimeout(() => { this.waiting() }, 5000));
    }

    waiting() {
        this.setState({ text: "Waiting for " + this.state.coffee });
        setTimeout(() => { this.finish() }, 5000);
    }

    finish() {
        this.setState({ text: "Here is your " + this.state.coffee + ". Enjoy!" });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.confirm(A, 10)} />
                <button onClick={this.confirm(B, 11)} />
                <button onClick={this.confirm(C, 12)} />
                <Barista text={this.state.text} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Barista extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: props.text
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            text: nextProps.text
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.text}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make a button call two functions at once? The way I have it set up is there a a button for the three brews, which sends the selected brew name and its price. Is there a way for the same button to also call the confirm()?

Comment: @eziodude98 add three button

Comment: I do have three buttons. I'm saying that I need the buttons to both send these values and start the confirm(). I can't use a 4th.

Comment: @eziodude98 you don't need more one button, when you click button, setState will impact props, automatically send text to Barista component

Answer (score 0):

After trying to figure out your goal, I guess this is what you need:

Firstly, you can define a father component, like App, which renders the Barista component **as well as a button component**, something like:

```
<button id="latte"></button>
<Barista />
```

Secondly, you will need to pass the `coffee` and `value` to the `Barista` component, so inside the App component you can change `<Barista />` to

```
<Barista coffeeName={this.state.coffee} coffeeValue={this.state.value} />
```

After that, you can access the `coffeeName` and the `coffeeValue` inside the `Barista` component with `this.props.coffeeName`...You can use them to show the information.

Last, add a function in the App component to modify the `coffee` and `value` state, and bind it to the button. For example,

```
<button id="latte" onClick={this.onClick}></button>
```

...

```
onClick(){...}
```

Hope this would help you.